# How can we implement efficiently a maximum set coverage arc of fixed cardinality?

Tags: graphs

I am working on solving the following problem and implement the solution in C++.

Let us assume that we have an oriented weighted graph $G = (V, A, w)$ and $P$ a set of persons.

We receive a number of queries such that every query gives a person $p$ and two vertices $s$ and $d$ and asks to compute the minimum weighted path between $s$ and $d$ for the person $p$. One person can have multiple paths.

After the end of all queries I have a number $k \le |A|$ and I should give k arcs such that the number of persons using at least one of the k arcs is maximal (this is a maximum coverage problem).

To solve the first part I implemented the Djikistra algorithm using priority_queue and I compute the minimal weight between $s$ and $d$. (Is this a good way to do ?)

To solve the second part I store for every arc the set of persons that use this arc and I use a greedy algorithm to compute the set of arcs (at each stage, I choose an arc used by the largest number of uncovered persons). (Is this a good way to do it ?)

I wonder also if there is another procedure that guarantees an optimal solution for $k \le 3$.
I am also wondering how can I implement it efficiently?

Comment: Would you be kind enough to credit the original source of the problem?

Comment: Can you give one or two simple examples?

Comment: It was given to me by a friend.

Comment: Although I don't think I have fully understood the problem, the greedy algorithm cannot be correct for all situations here.

Comment: You are right. It gives only a approxi

Comment: Can you be kind enough to ask your friend where he/she got it?

Comment: I think she got it from her homework

Comment: Tell me what don’t you understand and I can explain it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have so much time just to understand a problem. You are supposed to obtain the original statement of the problem and quote it here in the first place. Otherwise, you might be saving a few minutes of your time in the expense of many others' time. I am leaving now. Others, please pick up if you prefer.